# How to use mutiple Model in 1 View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I have 2 ViewModel

```
 public class PostViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public string CategoryID { get; set; }
    public int LikeNumber { get; set; }
}
public class CommentViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int CommentID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

And I created an another ViewModel

```
public class BigViewModel
{
    public List<CommentViewModel> CommentViewModels { get; set; }
    public List<PostViewModel> PostViewModels { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use them on 1 View

```
@model ShareImage.Models.BigViewModel
@foreach (var item in Model.PostViewModels.OrderByDescending(x=>x.CreateDate))
{


    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel panel-info">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3><b>TÀI KHOẢN:</b> @item.Username</h3>
                    <h3><b>NGÀY ĐĂNG:</b>  @item.CreateDate</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <img src="@Url.Content(item.Picture)" class="rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="@item.Description" style="width:900px;height:600px" />
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <h2>TIÊU ĐỀ:  @item.Title</h2>
                        <h2>Mô tả: @item.Description</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @Html.TextBox("Bình luận...") <button class="btn btn-success">Comment</button>

            </div>
            @foreach (var item1 in Model.CommentViewModels)
            {
                <div>@item1.Username</div>
                <div>@item1.Content</div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

But when I run it has an error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ShareImage.Models.PostViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ShareImage.Models.BigViewModel'.

This is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var db = new ShareImageDbContext();
        List<PostViewModel> model =new List<PostViewModel>();            
        var q = (from a in db.Posts
                 join b in db.Users on a.UserID equals b.UserID 
                 select new
                 {
                     postID=a.PostID,
                     title=a.Title,
                     description=a.Description,
                     createDate=a.CreateDate,
                     picture=a.Picture,
                     username=b.Username,
                 }).ToList();
        foreach (var item in q)
        {
            model.Add(new PostViewModel()
            {
                PostID = item.postID,
                Title=item.title,
                Description=item.description,
                Picture=item.picture,
                CreateDate=item.createDate,
                Username=item.username,
            });
        }
        return View(model);
     }
```

I have not completed the code for CommentViewModel in Controller. But i think it's not important, because I'm going to complete it later.

I have tried many ways to solve it but it's still can't work.
Please help me, thanks!

Comment: that implies to me that what you create on the controller and pass to the view is of type post view model.  can you post your controller code?

Comment: The error seems straight forward enough. Your view is expecting an `ShareImage.Models.BigViewModel` but you're passing a `List<ShareImage.Models.BigViewModel>` from your controller. You need to pass what is expected, so edit one or the other depending on whether you want to display one or multiple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one.This may help you.

Controller Change:-

```
 List<PostViewModel> model =new List<PostViewModel>(); 

  BigViewModel bigModel=new BigViewModel();
  bigModel.PostViewModels = model;
  return View(bigModel);
```

View Changes:-

```
@foreach (var item in Model.BigViewModel.PostViewModels.OrderByDescending(x=>x.CreateDate))
{
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. It worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your Welcome. Still is there any doubt ask.